# Solving a logarithm inequality

Tags: calculus

How would I solve $$\ln(1-2x) < \ln(3x+2)$$

I'm preparing for a test and I'm not sure how to tackle it.

Comment: Apply $\exp$ on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different conditions to be satisfied:

1. $1-2\,x>0$ (for $\ln(1-2\,x)$ to be defined)
2. $3\,x+2>0$ (for $\ln(3\,x+2)$ to be defined)
3. $1-2\,x<3\,x+2$ (because $\ln z$ is an increasing function of $z$)

Putting it all together, the solution to the inequality is
$$
-\frac15<x<\frac12.
$$

Comment: Would I be able to move both terms to the left and apply exp?

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to do it. Better apply exp directly.

Answer (score 0):

$exp$ is a monotonic increasing function, therefore you can apply it on both sides without changing the inequality :

$$1-2x < 3x + 2$$

Which leads to :

$$-1<5x$$

Finally :

$$-\frac{1}{5}<x$$